# Can you programmatically know the max blocks and threads per block in a GPU?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I am writing a CUDA program that will probably run on many different GPUs. I would like to know if CUDA provides some way of reading from code (either runtime or compile time) the capabilities of the current GPU, meaning the number of threads a single block can contain, and the maximum number of blocks, so I can tailor the launch of the kernel to optimally use all the resources.

I know it may sound like a silly question but I can't find any answers online.

Bonus question if it is not possible: I see [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-choose-how-many-threads-blocks-to-have/55529) that someone says they know the Jetson TX1 has

> 2 SM’s - each with 128 cores.
> I read that per SM (which I understand there are 2) there can be a maximum of 16 active blocks, and 64 active warps (or 2048 active threads).

How can I find this info for a given GPU?

Comment: IMHO, I would say no, as there is no standard among all the different graphics processors and displays.  When in doubt, look up the data sheet or programmer's guide for your target GPU.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Your opinion is blatantly wrong. Since the first CUDA beta, there have been APIs which expose these exact hardware characteristics to the programmer.

Comment: Can you explain why our's shop's display, using I2C to communicate, is not following the CUDA standards?  Our display has its own memory and "display list".  Instead of accessing the registers and memory directly, we have to send commands.  And yes, this is on an embedded system.

Comment: This entire question is about obtaining the hardware characteristics of NVIDIA GPUs in CUDA, which applies to every GPU NVIDIA has produced since about 2007. Is your embedded system using a CUDA compatible GPU? I guess not......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess [`cudaGetDeviceProperties`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0) seems to be what you are looking for.